# Storing uploaded files to NAS using PHP

Tags: php, file, upload, uploading, nas

I'm working on a website which allows users to upload pdf files. Is there a way to upload my pdf files to NAS using PHP? If there is, how? I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server Windows or Linux?
After you have connected the NAS to your server (so that it has his own path) you need a php upload script that puts the files in that path.

> Try to google: "Mount nas to [your OS]", "PHP file upload", "PHP absolute [your OS] paths"

Comment: running on windows. will that work even if the website is uploaded on a webhosting site?

Comment: You need php to be running on the machine that has the NAS mounted on.. if you want someone to upload files on your home NAS you need a static ip to host the upload site, otherwise files are going on the webhosting server and the only thing you can do is to download them